# Chrome extension automatically logs user out if they click on icon after logging in

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that uses firebase. I would like to not allow multiple logins from the same account and my code at least partially works. Meaning that you can’t login from a different browser if you are logged in somewhere else. The problem is that on the valid login once I leave the popup and click on it again it logs me out. Worse is that I cant log back in. It logs me in for half a second then immediately logs me out. I think it may have something to deal with the "auth.onAuthStateChanged" triggering immediately when I click on the Icon but I am not sure. Below is my service worker.

```
try{
    self.importScripts(
        'firebase/firebase-app.js',
        'firebase/firebase-database.js',
    'firebase/firebase-compat.js',
    );
  var config = {
     firebaseConfig :{
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      databaseURL: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "",
      appId: "",
      measurementId: ""
    }
  }
  

  // once it logis in it sends the ID here then we set and check if they are logged in. if they are already looged in. 
  //send sometimng to main. main will allert and say you need to logout
      //const app= initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.initializeApp(config.firebaseConfig);
     // const db=firebase.getDatabase();
      
      
const database = firebase.database();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const app = firebase.app();

// Function to check if the user is already logged in
function isUserLoggedIn(uid) {
  return database.ref("activeUsers").child(uid).once("value")
    .then(snapshot => snapshot.exists());
}

// Function to add a user to the activeUsers list on login
function addUserToActiveUsers(uid) {
  return database.ref("activeUsers").child(uid).set({
    timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
  });
}

// Function to remove a user from the activeUsers list on logout
function removeUserFromActiveUsers(uid) {
  return database.ref("activeUsers").child(uid).remove();
}

// Event listener for user login
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    const uid = user.uid;
    // Check if the user is already logged in
    isUserLoggedIn(uid).then(isLoggedIn => {
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        // Deny login since the user is already logged in
        auth.signOut().then(() => {
          console.log("Multiple logins not allowed. You were logged out.");
        });
      } else {
        // Allow login and add the user to activeUsers list
        addUserToActiveUsers(uid).then(() => {
          console.log("Login successful!");
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

// Event listener for user logout
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    // User is logged in, do nothing
  } else {
    // User is logged out, remove them from activeUsers list
    removeUserFromActiveUsers(user.uid).then(() => {
      console.log("Logout successful!");
    });
  }
});
}
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
      }
```

I also tried doing this in my content script but I always got this "error uncaught typeerror: firebase.database is not a function" which I also dont understand

```
let email=document.getElementById('email');
let password=document.getElementById('password');
let button=document.getElementById('submit');
let show=document.getElementById('discriber');

   
window.onload=function(){
  
button.addEventListener('click',function(){
 
  
login();

});


function login(){
   e=email.value;
   p=password.value;
   
    
 
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(e, p)
.then((userCredential) => {
  // The sign-in was successful
  const user = userCredential.user;
  console.log('User signed in:', user);
})
.catch((error) => {
  // Handle the error here
  const errorCode = error.code;
  const errorMessage = error.message;
  alert( errorCode);
  console.log('Error message:', errorMessage);
});


}


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
  
if(user){
  
  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
 
    show.innerHTML="logged In";
   
          
}else{
 
  localStorage.clear()
    chrome.action.setIcon({
                path : {
                  "32": "./logout.png"}});
                  
  
      show.innerHTML="logged out";
   
  
}
});


document.getElementById('logout').onclick = () => {
     logout()
   
  }

  function logout(){
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  
    show.innerHTML="logged out";
   
    alert("you are now logged out");
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: you need some way to tell if the new login is from the same browser as a previous one, then you should allow it. Maybe you can do something with session storage.